# How to do pd.fillna() with condition

Tags: pandas, if-statement, fillna

Am trying to do a fillna with if condition

```
Fimport pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,None,3,None],'b':[4,None,None,None]})
print df

df[b].fillna(value=0, inplace=True) only if df[a] is None
print df


  a   b
0 1   4
1 NaN NaN
2 3   NaN
3 NaN NaN
```

##What i want to acheive

```
  a   b
0 1   4
1 NaN 0
2 3   NaN
3 NaN 0
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can chain both conditions for test mising values with `&` for bitwise `AND` and then replace values to `0`:

```
df.loc[df.a.isna() & df.b.isna(), 'b'] = 0
#alternative
df.loc[df[['a', 'b']].isna().all(axis=1), 'b'] = 0
print (df)
     a    b
0  1.0  4.0
1  NaN  0.0
2  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  0.0
```

Or you can use `fillna` with one condition:

```
df.loc[df.a.isna(), 'b'] = df.b.fillna(0)
```